# what repo now hosts the equinox OSGi framework?

Tags: osgi, equinox

I created a demo [osgi-extensible](https://github.com/simbo1905/osgi-extensible) to do embedded OSGi to load dynamic rules. I can only find an old eclipse equinox 3.8.0 jar on maven central which gives a NullPointerException but the code runs fine with apache felix. Is there a repo which works with sbt/ivy/maven which has the newer equninox versions so that I can try those out?

Edit: Note the demo at the link above is looking to embed the eclipse equinox osgi runtime so just the osgi headers or bundle tooling would not answer the question

Comment: Have you checked http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/ ?

Comment: The question was about a Maven repository, not about a plain old download link.

Answer (score 1):

Equinox does not publish its artifacts to Maven Central, but some recent versions are published by the Tycho project. Check out [org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.osgi](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.eclipse.tycho%22%20AND%20a%3a%22org.eclipse.osgi%22).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I took a quick look but could not see an equinox framework jar. The demo code linked to in the question embeds an osgi runtime using jars obtainable by ivy/maven/sbt. So I am still seeking a repo which has the jar.

Comment: Despite its name, `org.eclipse.osgi*.jar` _is_ the Equinox framework JAR.